# How to revert Windows 10 1709 to 1703 without Windows.old being directly accessible?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, restore, windows-10-v1709

My question is comparable to [a former one](https://superuser.com/questions/1258956/revert-windows-10-from-1703-to-1607-after-the-revert-period), but a bit different as well: I'm using 1709 and considering "rolling back" to 1703 because of changes in [GDI memory management](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136952/mfc-ribbon-slow-on-first-loadshow.html) which introduced a [serious performance regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860377/very-slow-tortoisesvn-compare-to-base-since-win-10-fall-creators-update-local) with a lot of GUI tools and even Windows itself. As for the referenced question, my current system state doesn't provide `C:\Windows.old` and the easy ability to revert to 1703 anymore, BUT I have a snapshot which still contains that folder and a backup hard drive which still contains the entire old 1703 installation, backed up by simply using `wbadmin`.

Now Windows provides the "System Restore" capability to a former system state/snapshot and in that dialog my snapshot containing `C:\Windows.old` is still available:

[image: ShadowExplorer vs. System Restore]

So what happens when I restore to that snapshot? AFAIK the restore is not reverting the file system state entirely to that snapshot, that's why one can keep non-Windows related documents, images etc. So will System Restore consider `C:\Windows.old` as to be put back in place, with whatever piece of information Windows internally needs to provide me the ability to rollback to 1703 afterwards?

If that doesn't work, I still have my 1703 entirely backed up on the USB drive and I know how I can restore Windows to that state. The problem is that vs. System Restore AFAIK this means that the back up is completely put into place, loosing any changes to docs, images, mails etc. made after that backup.

Or am I wrong and something comparable to System Restore is available for my backup as well? So that I can point to my backup and Windows actually does something like a System Restore, only putting Windows 1703, apps etc. itself from the backup back into place, without touching docs, images etc.?

After I upgraded to 1709 and everything seemed to work reasonable well, I started to change directory layouts and such for my personal data, including the usage of Junctions and such stuff. Therefore I would like to revert Windows, if at all, in a way keeping all that work to my own data, especially as it doesn't influence Windows in any way. Of course I can simply create a new backup and put the changes back in place after restoring 1703 from backup and such, I'm just researching for ways how to avoid that work, especially because dealing with Junctions during restore can be tricky.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try installing from a 1703 install disc, saving personal data and applications. I've never tried down-grading this way, though I've often needed it to upgrade. Provided that the down-grade is allowed, it should leave your personal data and directory structures intact.

Comment: Windows doesn’t support downgrading.  So installing 1703 over 1709 likely will result in unpredictable results.  Using a Restore Point where Windows.old still exists should provide the ability to revert the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered a discussion I came across some months ago regarding consistency of Shadow Copies: Shadow Copies used for System Restore don't seem to guarantee consistency of files not related to Windows itself and whatever is needed/covered by System Restore. According to tests, unrelated files for Windows itself might be recovered using restoring to a former snapshot, but might be, and were in those tests, completely broken because their blocks have been used otherwise already and not protected using the snapshot. Simply because those are not needed by snapshots for System Restore and because the feature System Restore documents in the GUI that it doesn't influence user's data etc. So even if `Windows.old` would be available, it might be broken with unforeseeable side effects happening. Therefore I tend to not even test this approach, because besides the bug I'm seeing, my Windows is fully functional.

While the discussion is in German language, it might be interesting for others and mentions docs and error reports in English regarding this behaviour of System Restore and Shadow Copies. The arguments make sense in my opinion, because it's simply documented that snapshots can be created for various reasons/purposes, one can exclude files and directories from those and the examples for broken files were not seen in test made with backups created by `wbadmin`. That uses snapshots as well, but for other purposes/with other settings and according to the mentioned discussion, files part of snapshots created by `wbadmin` were never seen to be broken in any way. Which would make sense of course, as `wbadmin` has the broader use case compared to System Restore with really protecting all files.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-files/shadow-copy-snapshot-file-contents-silently/06a5e25b-6607-45eb-81a1-71cfc2b0cce3?auth=1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384976(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa819132(v=vs.85).aspx

https://www.heise.de/forum/heise-online/News-Kommentare/Windows-10-Fall-Creators-Update-kommt-am-17-Oktober/Re-Der-wichtigste-Schutz-vor-Ransomware-fehlt-natuerlich/posting-30976129/show/

https://www.heise.de/forum/heise-online/News-Kommentare/Windows-10-Fall-Creators-Update-kommt-am-17-Oktober/Re-Der-wichtigste-Schutz-vor-Ransomware-fehlt-natuerlich/posting-30978387/show/